# '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.time'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

There is already a question with the same title but I couldn't find an answer to my problem.. I am comparing times (in hour : minutes : seconds format) in a column to a set time (08:00:00) and having some issues.

I have imported some data from excel into a pandas dataframe. Some of the columns contain times. Their format in the dataframe is "object".
I started by creating a new dataframe containing only the data where  the times in the column "Starttime" are higher than 08:00:00 like this :

```
OSR_start_OH = pd.DataFrame()

OSR_start_OH = df[df['Starttime'] >= datetime.time(8,0,0)]
```

It works perfectly.

But then I try doing the exact same thing with another column "Finishtime" :

```
OSR_finish_OH = pd.DataFrame()

OSR_finish_OH = df[df['Finishtime'] >= datetime.time(8,0,0)]
```

And I get the error message  `'>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.time'`

I don't understand because the data in "Finishtime" column is in the same format as in "Starttime". In fact it is in datetime.time and not datetime.datetime :

The output for : `df['Finishtime'][3]`

is :    `datetime.time(20, 0)`

Also, I can compare different cells in the "Finishtime" column using '>=' :

The output for : `df['Finishtime'][3] >= df['Finishtime'][10]`

is : `True`

Edit : This is some of the data showing the date on "Finishtime" column for 00:00:00 times.

```
       Startdate    Starttime   Finishdate  Finishtime

350   2018-06-06      12:00:00  2018-06-06  15:00:00

351   2018-06-06      15:00:00  2018-06-06  19:18:17

352   2018-06-05      00:00:00  2018-06-06  14:47:54

353   2018-06-05      22:00:00  2018-06-05  1900-01-01 00:00:00

354   2018-06-05      00:00:00  2018-06-06  15:19:21

355   2018-06-05      22:00:00  2018-06-05  1900-01-01 00:00:00

356   2018-06-06      02:00:00  2018-06-06  14:48:45

357   2018-06-06      21:48:16  2018-06-06  02:00:00
```

Edit 2: this is what I get after trying 
`df['Finishtime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.time(x.hour, x.minute, x.second))`

```
   Startdate    Starttime   Finishdate  Finishtime
350 2018-06-06  12:00:00    2018-06-06  15:00:00
351 2018-06-06  15:00:00    2018-06-06  19:18:17
352 2018-06-05  00:00:00    2018-06-06  14:47:54
353 2018-06-05  22:00:00    2018-06-05  1900-01-01 00:00:00
354 2018-06-05  00:00:00    2018-06-06  15:19:21
355 2018-06-05  22:00:00    2018-06-05  1900-01-01 00:00:00
356 2018-06-06  02:00:00    2018-06-06  14:48:45
357 2018-06-06  21:48:16    2018-06-06  02:00:00
```

So the same as above

Any help is very welcome, Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a [MCVE]. Can you provide a dataframe to reproduce the error from scratch?

Comment: By the way this works for me: `pd.DataFrame({'dt': [datetime.time(8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2008, 1, 1)]}) >= datetime.time(8, 0, 0)`

Comment: The information in the dataframe is confidential, I could provide a minimal dataframe but it would just be two columns of information containing datetime.time data and it that case the code should work..

Comment: Hmm that's odd, it doesn't work for me, I get the same error message

Comment: Well, what I just provided is the kind of minimal example that is expected in a question :)

Comment: I use Python 3.6.3 and Pandas 0.23.4.

Comment: Either way, I'm pretty sure you have `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.time` values mixed up in your dataframe.

Comment: Yes you're right, by looking over the data I realised by chance that for the "Finishtime" column, the times "00:00:00" also have a date on them, I will edit my post so you can see, sorry for the ugly layout I can't figure out how to do it properly.. :/

Comment: There are formatting buttons on top of the edit window. I used code formatting after selecting your text: `{}`.

Comment: Ok thanks! How do I extract the time part of the datetime.datetime cells (the ones where the time is 00:00:00)? I can't seem to find a simple way to do it..

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, you have mixed types in your column `Finishtime`. 
You can extract the time for all values by applying this function:

```
df['Finishtime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.time(x.hour, x.minute, x.second))
```

Note: `x.time()` would work for `datetime.datetime` objects, but not for `datetime.time`. Since you have a mixture of both, the above workaround works for all types.

Comment: Hi! yeah I had tried x.time() and indeed that error came up. I have tried the above but it doesn't seem to work : I will edit my post to show you what I get

Comment: Hi again, I got round it by iterating down the column and using an if condition to use ````df.Finishtime[index] = datetime.time(df.Finishtime[index].hour, df.Finishtime[index].minute, df.Finishtime[index].second)```` on only the data which was of datetime.datetime type. I will add an edit to my post with the code I used tomorrow. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Good. That being said, in general you would be better off converting this to a pandas datetime column. This would be more efficient in all regards.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i had a similar error but finally it was a datetime column, my column 'datecolumn' had dates as:

```
0                   00:00:00

1        2018-08-01 00:00:00

2        2018-08-01 00:00:00

3        2022-07-05 00:00:00

4        2022-10-05 00:00:00
```

it technically does not have a date so it seems to me that it was the reason why it gives an error so I tried

```
df['datecolumn'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datecolumn'], errors='coerce')
```

to convert it as:

```
0              NaT

1       2018-08-01

2       2018-08-01

3       2022-07-05

4       2022-10-05
```

and it works for me, so maybe that's the issue with the date